# django haystack search for dots and minuses

Tags: django-haystack

I have product names in my search index like: **foo e-15**

I dont get a result when I search for **e-15** ist this normal? Is it possible to find strings with none alphabetical characters like **.** and **-** ?
Do this characters have superpower I don't know? :)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem when using xapian+haystack: couldn't get search results for query "Artist - Songname" in case of minus character.
Found that plus and minus characters work as search operators in xapian: [link](http://xapian.org/docs/queryparser.html)

But I still don't know how to change or fix that.